# AppleScript clickID script problems

Tags: javascript, macros, applescript

Okay I've been tinkering on this for a week now to no avail. Note: I am a beginner at scripting.

I am trying to make a script that navigates to a site, clicks the Search Button (which expands the search bar in order to type), & then types a search word.

Eventually, I want it to start exporting results to a document... but I cant seem to make the ID work or anything... Is it because it is a special type of search bar, not standard?

I've used various guides over the Internet and here's what I have managed:

```
to clickID("id")
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('theid').firstElementChild.click();" in document 1
    end tell
end clickID

-- Opening Safari to url

tell application "Safari"
    activate
end tell

open location "url"

delay 3

tell application "System Events"
    -- Open URL
    tell application process "Safari"
        delay 3
        clickID("theid")
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Your `clickID` handler needs to define a parameter instead of a string, and then needs to use it.  Where are you getting the element ID?

Comment: By inspecting the page and doing my best to decipher which ID it is that I need to click. U mean the first line of code that says: `to clickID("id")` If not a string there, then what?

Answer (score 0):

In a handler definition, parameters (if any) are declared that will hold the values passed to it.  In your posted snippet, the string "theID" would be passed to the `clickID` handler, and the parameter variable would be used wherever you want to use that string, for example:

```
to clickID(someID)
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById(\"" & someID & "\").firstElementChild.click();" in document 1
    end tell
end clickID

open location "url" -- activates default application

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Safari" -- click element
        delay 3
        clickID("theid")
    end tell
end tell
```

See the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-CJBIDBJH) for more information.